# How much are the bonuses for each choice at the end of Act 1?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

At the end of the raid on Loren's tower, you're given a choice to either set off the bomb or disarm the bomb.

For setting off the bomb, you get a permanent Respect bonus. For disarming the bomb, you get a permanent Cash bonus.

How much are each of these bonuses? Are they a one-time deal, like X amount of Respect/Cash at once, or are they an increased percentage of what you earn, like the perk you can buy that gives you 5% increased Respect earned?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get a 10% bonus to either respect or cash earned during the game.

Comment: The reward for the cash earned says that it is 10% to *all* cash earned, not just cash for missions/activities.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes have updated.

Answer (score 2):

It's permanent 10% cash income bonus for defusing and permanant 10% respect bonus for detonating. Personally I like the cash boost on your hourly income because this choice is offered to the player so early in the game, it makes more sense to bring in cash to upgrade weaponry and abilities, which in turn will upgrade your respect lvl. Also, the avg player is going to spend most of his time screwing around free roaming in the early game, which allows u to build cash anyhow, thusly, slapping the 10%+ on that makes more sense to me. I actually maxed out my weapons and bought all properties before the 11th or 12th mission. You don't want to play a larger portion of the game with weak weapons.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I defused the bomb and got a significant increase in my hourly income. I'm not sure off the top of my head how much it was, but respect is easy to earn/max out, so anything that brings more money tends to be a safe bet.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question, unfortunately. :/ I know Respect will eventually max, while money won't (though if SR2 is anything to go by, neither will be an issue later on), but I still want to know the exact bonuses for each choice at this time.