# What are the respective awards for Ho Boat?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

Similar to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36683/how-much-are-the-bonuses-for-each-choice-at-the-end-of-act-1), you again need to make a choice that will give you different rewards in the mission **Ho Boat**.

Choosing to give the hos back to Morningstar results in a lump sum of cash, while taking them back to HQ will give you increased cash flow over time. How much are each of these rewards?

Comment: I'd go for cash over time, as it is likely to eclipse whatever single payment one would get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Selling the hos back to the Morning Star = **Lump sum of $25,000**

2) Keeping the hos = **Increased cash flow of $1000 per hour**

Source: [Here](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ho_Boat)